# Pygame wont load my camera on Mac?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to access my webcam on Pygame to take pictures and save them BUT everytime I run the code:

```
import pygame.camera

import pygame.image

import sys

pygame.camera.init()

cameras = pygame.camera.list_cameras()

print ("Using camera %s ..." % cameras[0])

webcam = pygame.camera.Camera(cameras[0])

webcam.start()

# grab first frame

img = webcam.get_image()

WIDTH = img.get_width()

HEIGHT = img.get_height()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WIDTH, HEIGHT ) )

pygame.display.set_caption("pyGame Camera View")

while True :

 for e in pygame.event.get() :

     if e.type == pygame.QUIT :

         sys.exit()

 # draw frame

 screen.blit(img, (0,0))

 pygame.display.flip()

 # grab next frame    

 img = webcam.get_image()
```

I get this in IDLE:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Victor/Documents/Python Related/Python Code for Class/blah.py", line 5, in <module>
    pygame.camera.init()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pygame/camera.py", line 42, in init
    from pygame import _camera
ImportError: cannot import name '_camera'
```

Is there something I am doing wrong or another module I can install on Python that can take pictures through the internal or external webcam of the device and store it or send it where it needs to be?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) which is a robust tool for image acquisition and manipulation.

OpenCV accepts different languages and python is one of them, so you can just import the module and create a function that takes the picture and returns the image in a variable (or you can store the picture in a file and later read it).

Take a look at this link to get an idea of how to acquire images or videos with openCV 2 (and python 2.7)

https://codeplasma.com/2012/11/02/getting-webcam-images-with-python-and-opencv/

Or if you want to use the latest 3.0-beta version of openCV:

http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html

**EDIT:**

To install OpenCV on Mac you can follow the following link:

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/ios_install/ios_install.html#ios-installation

PD: You can also install Linux in your Mac and join the opensource comunity :)

Comment: [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/downloads.html) can be hard to install for mac, if the op doesn't have experience

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/camera.html) for `pygame.camera`:

> Pygame currently supports only Linux and v4l2 cameras.

Seeing as you're using a Mac and not Linux, this won't work. For the future, it is very helpful to read the documentation for libraries and modules you're using, since common issues such as this are usually addressed.

Comment: Well, I am new to Python. People make mistakes sometimes and I came for help and not to be criticized.

Comment: I updated my answer to be of a more neutral tone. Regardless, being new to Python shouldn't make a difference on whether or not you read the documentation for things you are using - only if you're new to programming in general would it make sense that you're not used to checking the documentation for modules/libraries. It's something every programmer should do, IMO.

Comment: I agree with @RandomDavis. You can't use ignorance as an excuse for everything. A simple google search told me that and also "New in pygame 1.9.0." so it could also be your version of pygame, even if it were possible for it to work on mac.

Comment: @VictorNwadike Don't take the answer as an attack on you. You made a mistake which can easily happen to everyone (I've done the same). But don't see criticism and help as two separate things. The critique you're getting is something that will help you the next time. When I stopped being defensive and started to take criticism I started to learn much faster. With that said, if you think someone is being mean in their criticism there's nothing wrong in expressing it and explaining why you felt as such. Random Davis saw your concern regarding his/her answer and did edit it to be more neutral.